# Is there a way to identify a specific pressed button created in a list? (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a variable-length list containing several buttons:

```
buttonList = [tk.Button(command=record,
                        text=str((i % MONTH_LEN[TIME.month]) + 1))
              for i in range(x)]
```

`x` is the length of the list of buttons (PREDEFINED!).

`MONTH_LEN` and `TIME.MONTH` shouldn't be needed of course; they're just part of the text.

I want to be able to differentiate between the different buttons being clicked WITHOUT needing to create masses of functions.

The most important part to note is that `record` should change a character in a string based on which button was clicked; the first button changes the first element in the string, the 20th button changes the 20th element in the string etc etc.

How can I achieve this? Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: One option is `functools.partial` to create function wrappers containing the current `i` value (`record` must then be adjusted to accept the additional `i` argument).

Comment: Well yes you can, easiest solution with multiple examples on the web is to use a lambda function that's passing an argument to your function.

Comment: Can you explain in baby terms? Functools is a new environment to me. Also, what would 'record' need to be adjusted to? Thanks for your help. @MichaelButscher

Comment: @Thingamabobs do you mean passing 'i' as an argument, then using it to change the specific element? If so, I'll make sure to give it a go. Thanks! :)

Comment: Yes, especially you can use "i" as index for your list, in case you need to address the button.

Comment: You can replace `command=record` with `command=functools.partial(record, i)` and `def record(...)` by `def record(i, ...)`.

Comment: @Thingamabobs Strange problem; 'i' is always 29 when I click any one of the buttons. I'll opt for iteration rather than list comprehension, which MAY help. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use lambda functions

Here is an example:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

x = 20

my_list = ['a'] * x

def record(index):
    my_list[index] = 'b'
    print(''.join(my_list))

buttonList = [
    tk.Button(
        command=lambda index=i: record(index),
        text=str(i),
        )
    for i in range(x)
    ]

for button in buttonList:
    button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

lambdas are a way to create "masses of functions" (as you put it) on the fly, without needing to give them names. The code `lambda index=i: record(index)` is pretty much equivalent to the following code:

```py
def noname(index=i):
    return record(index)
```

Note that we have to create a keyword argument `index` and set its default value to `i` in order to "capture" the value of `i` at each loop iteration. If we instead did `lambda: record(i)`, it would look up the value of i in the global scope, which will be equal to its value on the last iteration.

### Errata

> record should change a character in a string based on which button was clicked

Python strings are not mutable, unlike in many other languages. You cannot change them element-by-element. Actually, you cannot change them at all. You have to use a mutable container like `list`, and convert it to a string, as I did in my example.

Also, consider renaming `buttonList` to `button_list`. Using underscores is the convention in Python. You can read more about variable naming in [PEP8](https://pep8.org/).

Comment: works perfectly, thanks very much :)
i think my problem earlier was incorrect passing of index to record, which you've fixed! as well, don't worry about the poor name choice of buttonList; the name in my code is completely different. i just used buttonList as an example.